# Assigning USB hub to specific seat in multiseat configuration

Tags: usb, debian, xorg, udev, multiseat

On my debian-based machine, I have a working [multiseat configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration).

One annoying detail that so far I couldn't fix is that any USB hardware I connect is always assigned to the primary seat.

Scouring the internet, it seems that the solution to this problem is **to attach a USB hub to the machine and assign the "ownership" of it to the secondary seat**. This way, any device attached to the hub will be controlled to the secondary seat. However, **I'm a bit confused about how to assign the ownership**.

`lsusb` allowed me to track the bus position of the hub:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
```

**I will be most grateful if somebody will guide me from here...**

PS: Initially I thought I had to tweak the `xorg.conf` settings, but reading the conf.xorg documentation I couldn't find anything relevant. In some other post I also read about using `udev`, but again... I failed to find a clear how-to on how to achieve this.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps add a udev rule or intercept /proc/sys/hotplug with a wrapper to udev or an alternative hotplug system like mdev, diethotplug,hotplug2... A shell script is sufficient

Answer (score 3):

This Gentoo article might apply : [Multiseat](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Multiseat).

Configuration examples in this HOWTO are provided in great detail for a two-seat configuration, with seats labeled "left" and "right", but it is claimed to be easy to generalize to more seats.

The [udev section](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Multiseat#udev) especially describes how to assign the "left" and "right" tags to USB input devices
via the file `etc/udev/rules.d/99-seats.rules`, as well as the KDE desktop manager configuration
via the file `/usr/share/config/kdm/kdmrc`.

I hope that this applies to your configuration.